# Query error in Mysql compatible in-memory database (h2)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, spring-boot, h2

I was trying to perform some integration test on my spring boot application .Figured out that in-memory database is something which fits into our needs . Decided to go with h2 database.Currently we are working with mysql 5.5 version .I dumped create query from mysql . Sample query :-

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `test` enum('','of') NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I am using following dependency in pom.xml :-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.199</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Following error comes up if I execute this query on h2 :-

```
Empty enums are not allowed; SQL statement:
```

I am using h2 in mysql mode with connection as :-

```
jdbc:h2:file:~/test;MODE=MYSQL
```

Is there something which I can do regarding the same? If my datasource is mysql , is there any other good mysql compatible in-memory database . I have heard about mariaDB4j:mariaDB4j .

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug, the rule against empty values seems to break mysql compatibility mode which is requested in the connection string. Sure, for H2 native mode it can make sense, but that is not the use case here.

Answer (score -1):

The error is pretty clear, you can't use an empty value in the enum column. Use a value to denote emptiness, instead

```
[...]
`test` enum('','of') NOT NULL,
[...]
```

use

```
[...]
`test` enum('--','of') NOT NULL,
[...]
```

or

```
[...]
`test` enum(' ','of') NOT NULL,
[...]
```

Comment: This query works in mysql 5.5 version but not in h2 database . Is there any other in memory database which is compatible with mysql 5.5 ?

Comment: @yathartha I don't know.